# Plot emojis and words frequency

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot emojis and words frequency. 
After importing the libraries

```
import emoji
import regex
```

I have used the following function to count how many emojis and words are in the texts.

```
def split_count(text):
    emoji_counter = 0
    data = regex.findall(r'\X', text)
    for word in data:
        if any(char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI for char in word):
            emoji_counter += 1
            # Remove from the given text the emojis
            text = text.replace(word, '') 

    words_counter = len(text.split())

    return emoji_counter, words_counter
```

The code above was proposed as an answer to another user within this community. 
Since I have a list of strings, I would need to loop through them:

```
sent=["I know it's possible to match a word and then reverse the matches using other tools (e.g. grep -v). However, is it possible to match lines that do not contain a specific word, e.g. hede, using a regular expression?","I'm trying to iterate over the words of a string. The string can be assumed to be composed of words separated by whitespace. Note that I'm not interested in C string functions or that kind of character manipulation/access","I currently have a list of words within a text file, all the words within the document are on a separate line.",...]
```

I've tried as follows:

```
for line in sent:
        counter = split_count(line)
        print("Emojis - {}, Words - {}".format(counter[0], counter[1]))
```

it works pretty well, but I am not how to plot these results (emoji and words) in two separate charts (histograms), where on the y axis there is the frequency and on the x axis a label for each text (for example, first word).I hope in your help and advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple graph using the plotting function in 'pandas'. The data is created by adding it to the DF from the variables that have already been presented.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=[])
for line in sent:
        counter = split_count(line)
        print("Emojis - {}, Words - {}".format(counter[0], counter[1]))
        tmp = pd.DataFrame({'Emoji_cnt':counter[0], 'Word_cnt':counter[1], 'First word':str(line[:15])}, index=[1])
        df = pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

 df
    Emoji_cnt   Word_cnt    First word
0   1   39  I know it's pos
1   3   38  I'm trying to
2   1   22  I currently hav

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, subplots=True, layout=(2,1), sharey=True, sharex=True)
```

[image]